# Web Chat Application using Long-Polling Technology with PHP,MySQL and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, long-polling

We are using a chat system in our company which is build in Ajax, PHP and jQuery. Currently it refreshing in every second both in admin end and user end to pull data from mysql. Which makes the system inefficient and slower.

I want to pull data from mysql only when an user or admin send a message. But the problem is : How I will check from admin end that an user send a message (in real time)? **Is it possible in Ajax to send data/request 2 different PHP pages simultaneously in real time?** This may be a solution.

**Or Any Idea to make efficient chat system? We don't want to use any third party chat solution. Any Idea/help will be highly appreciated.**

Thanks,
Rejoanul Alam

Comment: Server can't start sending data to your browser without asking! Somehow, you have send a request to your server!

Comment: Just use [this](http://frug.github.io/AJAX-Chat/). It's complete, reliable, free and easy to customize.

Comment: I would recommend you to check websockets.

Comment: I am not sure what you a proposing is a good idea, If a user chats for a bit, and then is AFK for a while, they will not receive any further responses, until they send a message. Or when the do send a message the receive a large bulk of conversation that has gone on while they were away.

Comment: You should look into websockets

Comment: Thanks all for replies. I would like to specific my question more. Basically I want a chat solution only made by Ajax, jQuery and PHP. I need a faster chat system. I want to developed it from scratch. I am familiar with jQuery so looking for a jQuery, Ajax related technology for efficient chat system. My main concern is : HOW I CAN EXECUTE ANY CODE IN ADMIN PAGE (SAY admin.php) WHEN A USER SEND A MESSAGE (say user_message.php) in REAL TIME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery Long Polling**

This is possible by jQuery/PHP/MySQL with long polling. A sample implementation available in this url: http://sugunan.com/sites/chat/chatterFront.html

Open this in two different browser or machines. And provide the name and start the chat.

> The source code of this chat tool can be downloadable at this url:
>   http://www.sugunan.com/sites/chat/source.zip

**Node.js**

If you are owning the server you can go for `node.js` `faye` based implementation: http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html

This is a push notification technology. So it wont ping the server frequently. But it will deliver the message instantly. It can be integrated with PHP if you want to persist the message on server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there are any jQuery solution for that? I mean real time code execution in a different page.

Comment: I have edit the answer with jQuery working solution. If you are ok with that function let me know I will share the code. http://sugunan.com/sites/chat/chatterFront.html

Comment: Thanks @guru. Your jQuery chat system working nicely. But an continuous ajax request is being running there. Will this make the system slower? Anyway I want to see the source code. Would you please share the code for me?

Comment: @Rejoanul: I have place the source code as ".zip" file and share the url with the answer. As the source code is little lengthy I coudn't put it on the answer section.

Comment: @Rejoanul: is that source code working for you?

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks @guru. I am trying to use long polling, yet i am watching your codes. It helps my project.

Comment: @Rejoanul: If this really works, you can make my answer as green.

Comment: Thanks @guru. Would you please tell me about the techniques you used there? Such as which type of COMET it is? and why you used result.result?,    When more user will join in chat the "message" will contain huge data. Will it degrade the performance then?

Comment: More data i a common issue on DB not on chat technology. By frequently cleaning up the DB we can keep the performance up.

Comment: @sugunan: as of today 05/19/17 your links are broken ;)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are some ways,
They are called comet, sometimes reverse ajax, google it ;)

on a shared hosting use long polling,
on dedicated host or VPS use sockets.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am watching ...