# how to add real time chat with notifications in laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add real-time chat with notifications to my Laravel project.
 How can I do that and also save the chats in MySQL? Is there any chat framework that I can use??

Comment: Recently pusher has released a new chat API called [chatkit](https://pusher.com/chatkit), it could be a nice place to start. I don't know if it has persistance features, but you always can set some routes and save them async consuming the events provided.

Comment: you can do it using vue.js
follow this url:
https://jplhomer.org/2017/01/building-realtime-chat-app-laravel-5-4-vuejs/

Comment: I also used the same tutorial as @KuldeepMishra and it works great! I highly recommend it!

Comment: 1 google search of your question would have resulted in an answer..

Answer (score 2):

Because the best way to implement a chat uses websockets, which are not supported by default in PHP you need a service like pusher or running a [Laravel Echo server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) which is based on socket.io (a Node JS lib).

Pusher is something like "websockets as a service" and has a tutorial: https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/

And then there is this demo: 
https://github.com/jplhomer/laravel-realtime-chat-demo

If you cannot run or pay for any of the previously mentioned websocket implementations, you could consider using long polling in javascript, but that is a worse solution. It takes more resources and works far less better.
[Web Chat Application using Long-Polling Technology with PHP,MySQL and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682913/web-chat-application-using-long-polling-technology-with-php-mysql-and-jquery)